# Subview within the scrollview doesn't expand when contentsize increases

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift4

So I have a view hierarchy as:

UIView > UIScrollView > ContainerView

I have updated the contentSize of the scrollview and that scrolls fine. However, the ContainerView is limited to the original size of the ScrollView and that has made the areas after scroll non clickable.

See image attached. The ContainerView is in yellow color. As you can see, the view is scrolled well but the touches after Select Province is denied. I can't touch elements like Select City, Zipcode

**How do I increase the ContainerView's height OR allow the touches beyond visible area**

I've tried fixing it with heightConstraint to no avail.

```
profileScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: profileScrollView.frame.width, height: lastView.frame.origin.y + lastView.frame.size.height)

containerViewHeightConstraint.constant = profileScrollView.contentSize.height
```

[image]

Comment: try to set same frame of  scrollview to containerview

Comment: The height in the frame is same as design time height as only the contentSize changes, so containerView won't be expanded

Comment: have you checked what is profileScrollView.contentSize

Comment: I have even updated the frame for profileScrollView and replicated the same to containerView and it still won't expand :(

Comment: how you creating view and scrollview,

Comment: means using storyboard or xib or using code

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
profileScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: profileScrollView.frame.width, height: lastView.frame.origin.y + lastView.frame.size.height)

containerViewHeightConstraint.constant = profileScrollView.contentSize.height

self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```